# Kotlin - Evaluate functions from code string

Tags: kotlin, interpreter

**General Question:**

I would like to run in a kotlin app some code stored as String.

```
fun Evaluate(str: String,f:(s : String) -> Unit )
{
    f(str)
}
```

For example, an Hello World

```
var function : String = "fun a(s:String) = println(s)"
Evaluate ("Hello World",function)
```

Is this possible, or maybe something close to this result ?

**Specific Question :**

I have an activity containing a layout and a map of variable :

```
private lateinit var glayout: LinearLayout
val variable : MutableMap<String, Any> = mutableMapOf(),
val code : List<String>

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
   //Some init
   glayout = binding.root.findViewById(R.id.gamelayout)
   code = getCodeFromJson()

   for (c in code){
      //Here execute the code
   }
}
```

So i would like to be able in my interpreted code to :

- Modify a variable in the map
- Instanciate any kind of views in the layout, from text to button with onClickListener
- Run some specific android commands, like record, photo and others

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve with this approach?

Comment: I would like to have people able to make code that would interract with my application

Comment: In a way that they would submit the code, send it to your application and it'll run it? I belive things like that are usually done by creating separate files, compiling them and running the compiled files

Comment: More precisly : I have a screen with a layout. I would like to be able to write functions that would do anything. For example, instanciate a text or an image or a button, or add 1 to a mapped variable, etc

Comment: "*For example, instanciate a text or an image or a button, or add 1 to a mapped variable*" - would that change the state of the code that actually handles the GUI, or you would be okay with it being a child process? I would rethink the architecture of your solution. There is very little information given right now.

Comment: Also be aware that unless this is sandboxed really carefully, it's likely to open up a massive security vulnerability.  Running arbitrary code is normally something to be prevented at all costs.

Comment: I suppose it would be safer to write something like an API and to interpret myself the String as the API call, but that would lead to havent the possibility of leaving the possibility of my users to build their own specific ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the most reasonable way is to write a interpreter using your own language.

```kotlin
abstract class Interpreter {
    fun run(sentence: String) {
        val input = sentence.trim().split(" ")
        val cmd = input[0]
        val args = input.drop(1)
        execute(cmd, args)
    }
    
    protected abstract fun execute(command: String, args: List<String>)
}
```

---

For example, if you have a map and you want the user to modify it:

```kotlin
class MapInterpreter(private val map: MutableMap<String, String>) : Interpreter() {
    override protected fun execute(command: String, args: List<String>) {
        when (command) {
            "putmap" -> {
                require(args.size == 2) { "usage: addmap [key] [value]" }
                map[args[0]] = args[1]
            }
            "remmap" -> {
                require(args.size == 1) { "usage: remmap [key]" }
                map.remove(args[0])
            }
            "showmap" -> {
                require(args.size == 0) { "usage: showmap" }
                println(map)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To use it, just call the `run` method with the user input (from a text field, for example):

```kotlin
val map: MutableMap<String, String> = hashMapOf()
    
val interpreter = MapInterpreter(map)
interpreter.run("putmap I one")
interpreter.run("putmap V five")
interpreter.run("putmap X ten")
interpreter.run("putmap 2 two")
interpreter.run("showmap")
interpreter.run("remmap 2")
interpreter.run("showmap")
// Output:
// {2=two, V=five, X=ten, I=one}
// {V=five, X=ten, I=one}
```

---

Another example; to instantiate a Android View dynamically:

```kotlin
class ViewBuilderInterpreter(private val context: Context, private val parent: View) : Interpreter() {
    override protected fun execute(command: String, args: List<String>) {
        when (command) {
            "textview" -> {
                require(args.size >= 1 && args.size <= 2) { "usage: textview [text] {color}" }
                parent.addView(Text(context).also {
                    it.text = args[0]
                    it.color = if (args.size == 1) Color.BLACK else Color.parseColor(args[1])
                })
            }
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Of course that's just an idea, you also need to handle invalid commands and exceptions that might occur.

Comment: Yeah that was i thought as my backup solution. I already the very beginning of that (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68041709/android-linearview-dynamic-instanciation-of-views). My only problem here is to restrict the area of what is possible to what i implemented.